# How to find cheap accommodation in Europe

Tags: europe, budget, accommodation, booking.com

I'm touring Europe (Germany(Berlin and Munich),Austria(Salzburgh) and France(Paris)) for 11 days during Christmas and New year ( 24th Dec to 3rd January )

I would like to book the accommodation for cheap price.

Other than booking.com is there any other sites or ways to find cheaper accommodation in europe ?

Comment: "Cheap" means different things to different people. It might help if you specify a price range you're looking for. Short notice in the Xmas & New Year holidays might prove difficult.

Comment: AirBnB is an option - although it’s highly likely availability will be limited and prices higher than normal given the season. If you search eg ‘cheap accommodation in (XYZ city)’ you’ll get a raft of possible sites.

Comment: In German language look for Jugendherberge (hostel)

Comment: cheap and Christmas period don't match...

Comment: Just share me your destination place I will share you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CouchSurfing is an option if you are planning on only staying a day or two in one place.

[https://www.couchsurfing.com](https://www.couchsurfing.com/)

I have used the service myself on a couple of occasions to arrange for a single night accommodation.

People offer their couch/spare room/airbed for completely free and they're usually happy to be a local guide for you too.

There are some obvious safety and security concerns but the service does have a review system and you can always turn down someones offer if you are uncomfortable.

Answer (score 3):

Hostels, so just a bed in a shared room is likely the least expensive.

Hotel and hostel booking sites will help you find them.  Search online for 'hotel' or 'hostel' and name city to find booking sites.
Do double check on other sites for reviews. And check you can reach the location on the day, as some days public transport may be limited.

If you want private rooms, those same sites can help you as well but prices will be higher.

To get cheap accommodation at Christmas you need to book far ahead, as it is about a week till your travel date you will have to take what you can get.